# Spring Boot SimpleJdbcCall fails when Oracle Function has no input values

Tags: oracle, spring-boot

There are two Oracle functions that I need to call from a Spring Boot application. They are both in the same schema. One of the functions takes a String input value. The call to that function returns the expected result with no errors. The other function takes no input values. The call to that function results in the following exception:  java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1. I'm not sure why this is happening. I'll show the code for both the Oracle function and the Spring Boot call below.

Oracle Function:

```
create or replace FUNCTION "GETUNIQUEID" RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
returnuniqueid VARCHAR2(26);
BEGIN
  SELECT to_char(sysdate, 'MMDDYY-HH24MISS-')||manchester.globalpid.nextval INTO returnuniqueid FROM DUAL;
  RETURN (returnuniqueid); 
END GETUNIQUEID
```

Spring Boot code:

```
@Autowired
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

private SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCallFunction;

@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
                
  simpleJdbcCallFunction = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate)
                .withFunctionName("GETUNIQUEID");        
  String uniqueId = simpleJdbcCallFunction.executeFunction(String.class);
            
}
```

The exception thrown is java.sql.SQLException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1

Thanks very much for taking a look at this issue.

Comment: I think you still need the parentheses on function call.  Try           `.withFunctionName("GETUNIQUEID"());` Of course I never use double quotes so may need to be `.withFunctionName("GETUNIQUEID()")`;

Comment: Thanks. I just tried your suggestion, but  the same error message is thrown. I'm wondering if the issue has something to do with the way the Oracle function is written. This is legacy Oracle code. (I don't know anything about Oracle functions though).

Comment: It was worth a shot. You might have success by posting the function you are trying to call. At least the 'header'. But that is likely just another shot-in-the-dark.